# psql undefined symbol: PQsetErrorContextVisibility

Tags: linux, centos, postgresql

so i installed postgresql9.6 on my centos 7 server with bellow steps

> yum install 
>   https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm
>   -y
>
> yum install postgresql96 postgresql96-server postgresql96-contrib
>   postgresql96-libs -y
>
> /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
>
> systemctl enable postgresql-9.6.service
>   systemctl start postgresql-9.6.service

after these steps when i login to postgres user ( su postgres ) i cant operate psql command and it gives me this error :

> "psql: symbol lookup error: psql: undefined symbol:
>   PQsetErrorContextVisibility"

i have installed postgresql 9.2 successfully with no problems but i cant install postgresql9.5,9.6,10,11 and i get above error.

note : i have to install postgresql9.6 because i have a db backup from other server that has postgresql9.6.

Comment: Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303275/psql-symbol-lookup-error-psql-undefined-symbol-pqseterrorcontextvisibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I have fixed the issue by reinstalling my Centos 7 OS.
It seems like installing different versions of PostgreSQL created a complex for libraries that it used.